# android phonegap if timeout fallback

Tags: android, cordova

i'm trying to do a fallback on a timeout event!
ive set super.setingeterproperty("loadurltimeoutvalue", 60") so i can simulate it. Been searching around and havent found alot of answers to this.

I'm trying to do this: if timeout event -> load page from assets folder.
this so i can hide the error message that occurs on timeout. that error message contains the address to the site being loaded, and i dont want that at all to show up anywhere.

```
if (mWebView.loadUrlTimeout == currentLoadUrlTimeout) {
//super.loadurl("android_assets bla bla")
}
```

Found that code [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/callback/phonegap-android/branches/WebSockets/framework/src/com/phonegap/DroidGap.java), but cant get it to work. i think there are lots of parts missing, to the code, as i tried stripping it.
I am still pretty fresh to this, so there might be really logical flaws which i just dont see.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: have you tried using `super.setStringProperty("errorUrl", "file:///android_asset/www/error_page.html");` it seems to work

Comment: i m putting the same in answer so that you can close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting following property in the activity before loading the page, it should work:

`super.setStringProperty("errorUrl", "file:///android_asset/www/error_page.html");`

Answer (score 1):

`setStringProperty` has been deprecated in 3.0. Use config.xml instead:

```
<preference name="ErrorUrl" value="myErrorPage.html"/>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer up to date.

Comment: Where should you place myErrorPage.html? It doesn't load it for me when I put it in the same folder as the config.xml.